# How do I get associated products of product Group?

Tags: magento

I am looping through products results, and if the product is a grouped product, I want to get all products in that group. I'm doing this:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
foreach ($products as $product) {
    if ($product->getTypeId() == 'grouped'){
        // how do I now get associated products of $product?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In:

```
/magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/grouped.phtml
```

You'll see that they use this:

```
<?php 
    $_associatedProducts = $this->getAssociatedProducts();
```

Since that phtml file is of type `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Grouped`, we can go to:

```
/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Type/Grouped.php
```

and see that `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Grouped::getAssociatedProducts()` does this:

```
<?php
    $this->getProduct()->getTypeInstance()->getAssociatedProducts($this->getProduct());
```

So we can safely assume that `$this->getProduct()` returns a product object, and replace it with your `$product` variable like so:

```
<?php
    if ($product->getTypeId() == 'grouped'){
        // how do I now get associated products of $product?
        $associatedProducts = $product->getTypeInstance()->getAssociatedProducts($product);
    }
```

If I was to optimise your code completely, I'd write it like this:

```
<?php
    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'grouped'));
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $associatedProducts = $product->getTypeInstance()->getAssociatedProducts($product);
        // Do something with $associatedProducts
    }
```

Comment: Thanks I might get this to work... I want to iterate over all products, and IF it is grouped iterate over it's associated products - I still want all single products, not just associated products of grouped product. Your 'optimised' code would not include regular single products, am I right?

Comment: Correct, it would only get a collection of grouped products. What you want to use is $product->isGrouped(). So with your collection of all products, use: foreach ($products as $product) { if ($product->isGrouped()) { /* Get associated products collection */ } }

Answer (score 6):

Or if you want just to get ids of associated products, you can use the following method (it is much faster):

```
public function getAssociatedProductIds($groupedProductId)
{
    $coreResource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $conn = $coreResource->getConnection('core_read');
    $select = $conn->select()
        ->from($coreResource->getTableName('catalog/product_relation'), array('child_id'))
        ->where('parent_id = ?', $groupedProductId);

    return $conn->fetchCol($select);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To get product collection by type:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
   ->getCollection()
   ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'grouped'))
   ->load();

$parentProductId = array();

foreach($product as $simpleProducts) {
  $simpleProducts->loadParentProductIds();
  array_push($parentProductId,$simpleProducts->getParentProductIds();
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product::getParentProductIds() in /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php on line 1355

Comment: if you filter by grouped then $product collection does not contain simpleproducts