# Cross-sell all simple products from a group product together. Possible?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have multiple versions of a product which I'm grouping together into one grouped product. When I cross-sell them I want all of the simple products to be clickable (instead of the default, where Magento chooses one of the simple products). Basically like this:

[image: How I want cross-sells to appear on the cart page]

Comment: are you on Magento Enterprise ? The TargetRule module could have help ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy to your local store template /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/crosssell.phtml

```
<?php if($this->getItemCount()): ?>
    <div class="crosssell">
      .........

      <?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
        <?php if ($_item->getTypeId() == 'grouped')
        {
            $associatedProducts = $_item->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProducts($_item);

             <?php foreach ($associatedProducts as $ap): ?>
                   //display associated group products here
                   <li class="item">
                          ......
                        copy existing html structure and replace $_item with $ap
                        <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($ap->getName()) ?>
                    </li>
                <?php ?>
          <?php }
               else
               { ?>
                 <li class="item">
                     ......
                     // copy existing code here
                 </li>
          <?php } ?>

       <?php endforeach; ?>

         .................
```

See [Magento - how do I get associated products of product Group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579765/magento-how-do-i-get-associated-products-of-product-group)